# Remove a block of a log that doesn't match a pattern (multiple lines)

Tags: regex, vim

How to remove a block of info that doesn't match a specific pattern, illustrating:

```
[received]
   some_text
   ...
   MYPATTERN
   some_other_text

[received]
   some_text
   ...
   IGNORED_MESSAGE
   some_other_text

[sent]
   some_text
   ...
   ALSO_IGNORE_THIS_ONE
   some_other_text

[sent]
   some_text
   ...
   MYPATTERN
   some_other_text
```

How to use `:s` OR `:g` to keep only packages, block info, with `MYPATTERN`, the spected result is:

```
[received]
   some_text
   ...
   MYPATTERN
   some_other_text

[sent]
   some_text
   ...
   MYPATTERN
   some_other_text
```

If it is too complex for a single command a function could be suggested.

Comment: `%g!/\(.\+\n\)*.\+MYPATTERN.*\n\(.\+\n\)*/d` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Empty a register, say register `h`:

   ```
   qhq
   ```
2. Cut all the matching blocks into register `h`:

   ```
   :g/MYPATTERN/normal "Hdap
   ```
3. Delete the whole buffer:

   ```
   :%d
   ```
4. Put the content of register `h`:

   ```
   :put h
   ```

Comment: Very nice.  The big trick here is knowing that `dap` will delete a full section at once.

Comment: @RandyMorris, thank you. There's a special kind of beauty in complex regular expressions but it is often easier and quicker to come up with that kind of solution, at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
%s/\v\[((MYPATTERN)@!\_.){-}\n\s*\n//
```

Regex explanation:

- `\[` to match the start of each paragraph
- `\_.` matches any character, including end-of-line
- `{-}`  matches 0 or more times, similar to `*` but non-greedy (as few as possible)
- `((MYPATTERN)@!\_.){-}` - any number of characters that aren't preceded by MYPATTERN - see `:help \@!` for more info
- `\n\s*\n` matches an empty line, which marks the end of the paragraph

Comment: I just need to add a char to make your statement work in real situation, it was `^` resulting: `^\[`, because in real situation [] uses to appear, but not at the first line. Without it, it took > 3 minutes, with it it took less than one.
`%s/\v^\[((MYPATTERN)@!\_.){-}\n\s*\n//`